# Localization Language resource ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, localization, resources

Hi I want to localize my application for Slovencina for iPhone.

[image]

But I am unable to find proper localization category from the xcode localization list.
I have tried: [image]

Further I have also tried changing the region to slovencina...

Please help me to select proper localization files for the application..

Comment: It was the issue with simulator, worked fine in Device. (sl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Localization has some issues with iOS Simulator. I have also faced same issue back then while I was testing my application. Try to test it on real device.
Hope it works. :)

Comment: Thanks alot. It is fine with device.